# Mysql Doctrine2 foreign key failing

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Hi have setup a db with tables States and StoreLocations. I have created entities for both. As well as RESTful services. When posting a new Location on my local machine everything works fine.

I have deployed my project to another server and when I try to post a new Location on this machine I get the following error

```
Code: 23000 
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vitanica`.`StoreLocation`, CONSTRAINT `storelocation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`id`))
File: /home/audioglobe.com/zend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php
Line: 131
```

I do not understand why this would work on one machine and not another. Thanks in advance for any thoughts on the issue!

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> show create table StoreLocation

| StoreLocation | CREATE TABLE `StoreLocation` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
`state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`zip` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `state` (`state_id`),
CONSTRAINT `storelocation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `state` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

mysql> show create table State

| State | CREATE TABLE `State` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

And a snippet from my Entities:

```
/** @Entity */ 
class State
{
  ....
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="StoreLocation", mappedBy="state") */
    private $stores;
}

/** @Entity @HasLifecycleCallbacks*/
class StoreLocation
{
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="State", inversedBy="id")
    */
    private $state;
}
```

Comment: That often happens when you are not setting one side of a bidirectional entity.  Are you creating the `State` and the `StoreLocation` at the same time?  If not, is the `State` table populated?

Comment: State is fully populated. Just commented out all code inside the post route. When resubmitting I am seeing alot of strange output:

Comment: `b0VIM 7.3�,ZP��#server/zend/routes/storelocator.phputf-8 3210#"! Utp�ghad(�g��R2 �������nP0 � � � } o j e C !  ����kMJ��^ZY#� � � � T  � � � j  ���(����8��� ����%$����mEC,������V����{=����});`

Comment: Not sure where this is coming from I am not running any code inside the route.

Comment: Looks like the content of a `vim` swapfile.

Comment: I did edit the file using vi and then save. Not sure if that would cause it. I can try saving locally and updating my repo

Comment: Yep that removed the strange chars.. I am going to debug a little more. But old problem still exists, and yes i have populated States with id's 1 - 50.

Comment: Here is my code inside the route:

Comment: `$store = new \SES\Entities\StoreLocation;`
`$state = $em->getRepository('SES\Entities\State')->findOneBy(array("code" => $req->post('state')));`

Comment: if i `echo $state->getName();` It outputs the state name; So I know its finding the state, next I call `$store->setState($state)` then persist and flush

Comment: It seems like this code is ok, and it is working 100% on my local env

Comment: If it works locally and not on the remote server, then either the database is different somehow, or perhaps a different version of Doctrine or something.  You definitely have the same code uploaded I assume?  Easy to have one of the Entity files out of sync.

Comment: I am using svn so the code should be the same. I can't find any differences in the databases either. Ill create a couple of db dump files and post links

Comment: I ran a `mysqldump` and then stored that file in svn. I made sure to run `mysql table < db.sql` So I would assume the structure should be the same on both dbs.

Comment: Another thing to note. If I modify an existing location and leave the state the same it does not give me this error and my entity updates. In my code I am selecting the state from the `$em` and then setting this on the location. This happens even if the state does not change. Again if I change the state and update I get the error.

Comment: Sounds like it's losing the ID still to me in one half of the bidirectional.

Comment: Yea not sure why it would lose it in one env and not the other. I just check mysql versions locally i am running 5.1.44 and on prod 5.5.14 Not sure if this would cause the error. May try updating mysql locally, not sure safest way to do that, if you have any thoughts on it. I am running OSX locally

Comment: Found the error: The fk from the dump is as follows: `  CONSTRAINT storelocation_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state (id)` The problem is that the table name is State not state. My local machine does not have a problem with case sensitivity but it appears my prod does. Any thoughts?

Comment: I always assume everything in the universe is case-sensitive to avoid any such problems.  It is certainly poor that the same software is case-sensitive in one place but not the other, hard to say why.  Could be down to the version, glad you discovered the issue at anyrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the fk was failing because mysql was case-sensitive on production. The table name was `State` though the constraint referenced `state(id)`. I changed all table names to lower case and added the property `@Table('state')` to my Entity. Now everything is working as expected! Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I've to set name="state" in the annotation

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the constraint is that, within `StoreLocation`, you can't have a `state_id` that is not also present in the `State` table.

Have you populated your `State` table with a complete list of states?

Comment: Yes I have, Seems like there is another issue that may be causing this problem, see comment above